# LensStudio: Is it possible to set a layer number through script

Tags: typescript

In lens studio you have a layer option where you can set the layer number of a object. I've tried searching for a layer set but lens studio only shows layer names. So you can put stuff in a different layer name. But that's mostly for the camera. I'm Searching on how to set the layer number.